# Adding or Replacing a new Panel to inside a Window in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

---

**Problem has been solved already,
Thanks anyways :)**

---

I've got a Ext.Window object.
something like:

```
var mypanel= new Ext.Panel({title:'Placeholder'});
var cwin = new Ext.Window({
    layout:'fit',
    width:screen.width-200,
    x:200,
    y:150,
    draggable: false,
    closable: false,
    resizable: false,
    plain: true,
    border: false,
    items: [mypanel]
});
```

I'm trying to replace 'mypanel' with another Ext.Panel object when the user triggers a specific event.
So i figured I could remove mypanel and than add a new panel to it.
I got the removing working.
The adding however is a different story,
I've tried stuff in the direction of:

```
mypanel= new Ext.Panel({title:'my new Panel'});
cwin.add(mypanel); //dit nothing
cwin.items.add(mypanel); //dit nothing
cwin.insert(0,mypanel); //dit nothing
cwin.items.insert(0,mypanel); //dit nothing
```

I'll be happy with any answer for either replacing the existing panel or adding a new panel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding items, you should call doLayout() on the container.

```
// remove actual contents
cwin.removeAll();
// add another panel
cwin.add( new Ext.Panel({title:'my new Panel',width:300,height:400}) )
// repaint with new contents
cwin.doLayout();
```

should do the trick